# How cairngorm suites for Flex 4.5 mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5, cairngorm

Can cairngorm framework suites for developing mobile application using flex 4.5 ?

Comment: Voting to close for lack of content.  Also, see other Cairngorm related question you asked.

Comment: i know how to develop Flex application using cairngorm framework. but now i have to develop the mobile application. so i have a doubt on developing the mobile application using cairngorm.